# Issue in installation of Robotframework

Tags: robotframework

Installed python and pip. Configured environment varaibles. When I am trying to install robotframework using the cmd by typing in `Pip install robotframework`, It throws first the warning message and later it says:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robotframework

or

> No matching distribution found for robotframework.

I tried entering command like

```
pip install robotframework

pip install robotframework=5.0.1 (version)
```

i tried the above 2 commands but it didnt work out.

Comment: what is the warning message saying?

Comment: No matching distribution found for robotframework. -- This one

Answer (score 0):

You may be having problems in accessing Pypi.

See if you can access the page at [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework/).

And you can try to install directly from it with:

```
pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/72/26/5a391509c611bda444e73228a89694accac1f1e6e84c11964ba163b81b1a/robotframework-6.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
```

Other option is to install from project page:

```
pip install https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/archive/refs/tags/v6.0.2.zip
```